# Can I use a cmake-modules folder without setting CMAKE_MODULES_PATH in each project?

Tags: cmake

Is there some environment variable, that can replace setting `CMAKE_MODULES_PATH` in each project, that needs my `cmake-modules` folder, that has some additional `Find<Project>.cmake` files?

I tried `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`, and `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` (not documented to work as environment variable) and they did not work.

I could patch my own projects to add `$ENV` paths to the `CMAKE_MODULES_PATH` variable of the project, but I would like to use it for other libraries as well.

Comment: From [find_package documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/find_package.html), "The file is first searched in the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, then among the `Find Modules` provided by the CMake installation.". So, no environment variable affects on that search. However, you may pass option `-DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH=/path/to/your/modules` to `cmake`, this would set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` CMake variable.

Comment: I would really like any workaround, as I need to write a documentation for installing quite a few cmake projects in Windows. There cmake-gui is the easier path, as using the cmdline is for most users rather uncommon. I currently recommend to add ``CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`` in each project that needs the modules, but a global setting would be much better.